# Prometheus alert expression during the special period of time

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I got the following Prometheus alert:

```yaml
- alert: HostHighCpuLoadTSDB
        expr: (100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",common_name="stg-tsdb-eks"}[2m])) * 100) > 5) and (hour() < 8 or hour() > 9)
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: Host high CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
          description: "CPU load is > 5%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

expression:

```
(100 - (avg by(instance) 
    (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",common_name="stg-tsdb-eks"}[2m])) * 100) > 5) 
and (hour() < 8 or hour() > 9)
```

And each part works fine. For instance, when I create an alert rule with the expression:

```
100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",common_name="stg-tsdb-eks"}[2m])) * 100) > 5
```

it creates alert.

When I create an alert rule with the expression: `hour() < 8 or hour() > 9` - it creates an alert.

So, it means that both conditions are met: time in hour is less than 8 or more than 9, cpu load is more than 5%
But when I put it together: `(100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",common_name="stg-tsdb-eks"}[2m])) * 100) > 5) and (hour() < 8 or hour() > 9)`  - it doesn't create an alert.

Can someone point me in the right direction, what I'm doing wrong?

Prometheus version: v2.41.0
Alertmanager version: v0.25.0
I'm running it in the kubernetes cluster as kube-prometheus-stack deployed as Helm chart

I want to create an alert when the CPU load is more than 5% during any period of time, except the period between 8 and 9 hours(or even 10, it doesn't matter), during that period I don't want to trigger the alert. I'm testing it at let's say 12 o'clock and it still doesn't trigger the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by `and` in your query. It tries to match left part with label set (instance) and right part with empty label set.

You should use `and on() (hour() < 8 or hour() > 9)` to resolve this.

Demo can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up%20and%20hour()%3E10&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1d&g1.expr=up%20and%20on()%20hour()%3E10&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1d).

Generally, if you want to create alert rule, I would suggest to go to Prometheus' GUI (something like `localhost:9090/graph`), paste you expression into query field, switch to graph tab and select appropriate time range (`1w` for example).

That way you'll have a chance to see when your alert would here in past, if it were created earlier.

Also, I believe you could use

```
unless on() hour()>=8 <=9
```

instead of composite `and` clause, to increase readability of your rule